# Making a 3D surface from time series data in R

Tags: r, 3d, geometry-surface

I have a large data set which I would like to make a 3D surface from. I would like the x-axis to be the date, the y-axis to be the time (24h) and the z-axis (height) to be a value I have ($). I am a beginner with R, so the simpler the better!

http://www.quantmod.com/examples/chartSeries3d/ has a nice example, but the code is way to complicated for my skill level!

Any help would be much appreciated - anything I have researched so far needs to have the data sorted, which is not suitable I think.

Comment: I would suggest trying to figure out how that figure was made and then asking more specific questions based on where you get stuck.

Comment: Check out the `lattice` package,  in particular see the examples for `wireframe` (you can do this by loading the `lattice` package then running `example(wireframe)`).

Comment: If you post some sample data it will be much easier to help you.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/602276 for tips on asking a great question

Answer (score 7):

Several options present themselves, `persp()` and `wireframe()`, the latter in package **lattice**.

First some dummy data:

```
set.seed(3)
dat <- data.frame(Dates = rep(seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() + 9, by = 1), 
                              each = 24),
                  Times = rep(0:23, times = 10),
                  Value = rep(c(0:12,11:1), times = 10) + rnorm(240))
```

`persp()` needs the data as the `x` and `y` grid locations and a matrix `z` of observations.

```
new.dates <- with(dat, sort(unique(Dates)))
new.times <- with(dat, sort(unique(Times)))
new.values <- with(dat, matrix(Value, nrow = 10, ncol = 24, byrow = TRUE))
```

and can be plotted using:

```
persp(new.dates, new.times, new.values, ticktype = "detailed", r = 10, 
      theta = 35, scale = FALSE)
```

The facets can be coloured using the `col` argument. You could do a lot worse than study the code for `chartSeries3d0()` at the page you linked to. Most of the code is just drawing proper axes as neither `persp()` nor `wireframe()` handle `Date` objects easily.

As for `wireframe()`, we

```
require(lattice)
wireframe(Value ~ as.numeric(Dates) + Times, data = dat, drape = TRUE)
```

You'll need to do a bit or work to sort out the axis labelling as `wireframe()` doesn't work with objects of class `"Date"` at the moment (hence the cast as numeric).

Comment: @Mark McMullan If you are satisfied with an Asnwer please marker it accepted by checking the big tick mark to the left of the answer. No worries if this isn't a final complete answer, you don't need to accept such answers.